# Fetching nested data, undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to fetch data from API, but I'm only able to fetch the highest level ones. When I'm trying to access ones nested under categories, I get an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data.order.name' )`.

From what I've read it might be an issue with state but I'm new to react-native and I am not sure how to fix it.

This is the API structure

[image: This is the API structure]

```
 render(){
    const { data } = this.state;

 return(
  <ScrollView style={styles.containerxd}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textStyle}>
  <Image
     source={require('./images/burger.png')}

     style={styles.ImageIconStyle} />
    </TouchableOpacity>

 <View style={styles.white}>

        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}> 

  <View style={styles.tabHeader}><Text style={styles.textHeader}>Scientific name</Text></View>
  <View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{this.state.data.scientific_name}</Text></View>

  <View style={styles.tabHeader}><Text style={styles.textHeader}>Common name</Text></View>
  <View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{this.state.data.common_name}</Text></View>

  <View style={styles.tabHeader}><Text style={styles.textHeader}>Moisture use</Text></View>
  <View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{this.state.data.order.name}</Text></View>
```

Scientific name and common name show up just fine, but every data level lower renders error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate your data.When order is undefined, doing `order.name` will break your app. change

```
<View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{this.state.data.order.name}</Text></View>
```

to

```
const { data } = this.state;
const name = data && data.order && data.order.name || '';

// rest of the code here
<View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{name}</Text></View>
```

**NOTE**

Always validate your data. Don't assume that you'll always get the right data. When working with objects always validate them, as doing `data.name`, can break your app, if `data` is null or undefined. for example, given the following object.

```
const animal = {};
```

doing

```
// throws an error, Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
console.log(animal.name.toLowerCase())
```

to prevent that from happening, we need to check if the propery exists, like the following.

```
// checks if the name property exists console name, else assign a console log 'Lion'
console.log(animal.name && animal.name.toLowerCase() || 'Lion')
```

**Second option**

add a loader, display `Loading...` text when fetching data from api, once the request finish set loader to false and display your data.

```
fetchData = async () => {

  const res = await fetch(...)
  ...
  this.setState({ isLoading: false, data: response.data });
}

render() {

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.containerxd}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textStyle}>
        <Image
          source={require('./images/burger.png')}
          style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {this.state.isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.white}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center'
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.tabHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Scientific name</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.tabContent}>
              <Text style={styles.textContent}>
                {this.state.data.scientific_name}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.tabHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Common name</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.tabContent}>
              <Text style={styles.textContent}>
                {this.state.data.common_name}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.tabHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Moisture use</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.tabContent}>
              <Text style={styles.textContent}>
                {this.state.data.order.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, yeah. Everything works now. Thank you so much!